# Console not showing error

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Google chrome has stopped showing all the JavaScript exceptions

I have tired

1. To reset under the the dev tool under (setting > restore default and reload)
2. Reset chrome
3. Deleted AppData\Local\Google and reinstall Chrome

Not too sure what to do !

Version 65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Error is thrown from: Angular.js file

[image]

Comment: I just ran into this exact same issue. I too have the small pinkish bar at the top and no errors will show. I don't recall doing anything out of the ordinary. All of a sudden this just happened.

Comment: Shame here, also with angularJs

Comment: I've just come across the same issue. Console is reporting errors but no indication or message as to what the error is apart from a link to the JS file in question!

Comment: Happen to me this morning after chrome update. Any updates on how to fix this?